# Resolving the 'weird number' and gobble issue in springer journal template

Tags: springer

So I'm trying trying to write my journal in `sn-jnl` class. The cls file can be found [here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support/see-where-our-services-will-take-you/18782940).

Although my latex file is compiling, but there are issues which I want to figure out:

1. Its throwing errors on the `\begin{document}` line regarding the missing number issue. which I don't know why its happening.
2. Somwhow, the packages (or a single package) is causing this random error:

[image]

Regarding the second point, I tried eliminating all the packages in try to figure out which pakcage is causing that, but I couldn't figure out the problem. Remove some packages and this `A[gobble]` thing becomes more random garbage. For reference, I'm using overleaf with pdflatex. Also, i'm using this exact same preamble in another journal using the IEEE `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}` class, and it doesn't throw a single error. It's only when i'm using the sn-jnl class when erros start showing up.

MWE reproducing the error:

```
\documentclass[iicol]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{Center}{\hfil#1\hfil}
\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\hfil(\makebox[0.7em]{#1})\hfil}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\\ // #1}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\newcommand{\SP}{\textbf{Start Procedure:}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=none,
bibstyle=ieee
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{My_references.bib}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\newpage
This is my file

\end{document}
```

Comment: the class is faulty, it uses a command of a package without loading the package. Add `\usepackage{manyfoot}`.